# Too many TCP ports in CLOSE WAIT condition in kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

Too many TCP Connections are in CLOSE_WAIT status in a kafka broker causing DisconnectionException in kafka clients.

> tcp6      27      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.0.47:45138       ESTABLISHED -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:41612      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.0.47:45010       CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:43000      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6     194      0 172.31.10.143:8080      172.31.20.219:45952     CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.20.219:48006     CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6       1      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.0.47:44582       CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:42828      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:41934      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:41758      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:41584      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6      25      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.46.69:41852      CLOSE_WAIT  -
>   tcp6       1      0 172.31.10.143:9092      172.31.0.47:44342       CLOSE_WAIT  -

Error in debezium

> connect-prod | 2019-02-14 06:28:54,885 INFO || [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=4] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1727876188, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException. [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler] connect-prod | 2019-02-14 06:28:55,448 INFO || [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=4] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1379896198, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException. [org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler]

What can be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue in Kafka 2.1.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7697

I think the connections stuck in Close_wait is a side effect of the real problem.

This issue has been fixed in Kafka version 2.1.1 which should be released in a few days. Looking forward to it.